# Is it possible to hide an element in array when the array is printed to the console?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am learning the Java language, and right now I am doing a little project that is called a battleship game.

Question: I want to fill a char array with random characters in a specific index but when the whole array is printed in the console, these characters should not be visible to the user because based on these characters the user will hit these characters.

Comment: If you have specific indices then you can just check whether it's one of those before printing?

Comment: Please provide your source code to begin with. It is better to point you to where things are going wrong in your source code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution would be to just check whether the char should be hidden or not when printing them out:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    
    //your char array
    char[] charsArray = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    //chars you want to hide
    char[] charsToHide = {'b', 'd'};
    
    //loop over you char array
    for (char myChar : charsArray)
    {
        
        //check if element is a char to hide
        if (containsChar(myChar, charsToHide) == false) 
        //if not, print it
        {System.out.print(myChar);}
        
    }
    
}

public static boolean containsChar(char myChar, char[] charsToHide)
{
    
    //loop over all chars to hide
    for (char charArrayElement : charsToHide)
    {
        
        //check if you char is part of chars to be hidden
        if (myChar == charArrayElement) {return true;} 
        
    }
    
    return false;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create another helper array to store the random char's index you want to hide from the console. When you are printing to console check if the current index matches with the index you want to hide from the array you just created to store the indexes.

Ok.... let's say you have w int in the newly created index holder array. And your main char[] has n elements. If you do a brute force this will cost you O(n * w) complexity. Roughly O(n^2) complexity. So, a better approach would be you should populate the helper array in ascending order. And then perform a binary search. The complexity would be then O(n * lgW). Another optimization can happen using a hashmap.